# How to move behind autopaired char in insert mode in vim

Tags: vim

I am using `auto-pair` in Vim (https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs). I am typing code:

```
= link_to 'Link name', some_path(@var|)
```

And the cursor in edit mode is at `|` position. Then I want to continue typing more params.

What is the fastest way to move cursor behind the auto-paired `)`?

I know I can press `Ctr-O Shift-A` but 4 key strokes to move cursor one column to the left is over-kill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the right/left arrow keys, but the way the plugin provides a better way of doing it.  If your cursor is right next to the closing auto-paired character, you just need to type that character.  For instance, if your cursor is in a position like this:

```
def some_func(args|)
```

You can just press `)` to go to the right of the auto paired character.  Same goes for any other closing characters that auto-pairs is compatible with.

Comment: Yea, but for `)` character it'll result in `def some_func(args(|))`

Comment: That's not how it works in my auto-pairs configuration.  Have you tried it yet?

Comment: Oh, it works now. But I had to enable Fly Mode - `let g:AutoPairsFlyMode = 1`. Do you have this in your `.vimrc`